# css display:block doesn't display all elements

Tags: css, margin, navbar

All my li elements allying at the same spot on on top of the other even tho they are supposed to use the display block.
The nav bar simply displays the sub-menu under the regular menu, but all the ul,li are on top of each other.

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li class="left"><a href="/scripts">Scripts</a>
        <ul>
                <li>
                 <a href="#">test1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                 <a href="#">test2</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                 <a href="#">test3dfgdsfgdfsg</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                 <a href="#">test523542352543253q4teargt</a>
                </li> 
        </ul>       
    </li>
```

Yes i know the code is very messy

```
ul.navbar {
list-style: none;
bottom: -30px;
padding: 0;
}

ul.navbar li.right {
    float: right;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: block;
}

ul.navbar li.left {
    float: left;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: block;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #3366CC;
    margin: -30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 25px;
}
ul.navbar li ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover {
    background: #4075DE 
}

ul.navbar li ul li a {
    display: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin:0px;
}

ul.navbar li:hover ul a{
    display: block;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
```

Comment: That position absolute and your negative margins are mighty suspicious. How does this look? http://jsfiddle.net/v1kq7dva/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove position: absolute on the a{}
http://jsfiddle.net/v1kq7dva/

```
ul.navbar {
list-style: none;
bottom: -30px;
padding: 0;
}

ul.navbar li.right {
    float: right;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: block;
}

ul.navbar li.left {
    float: left;
    line-height: 14px;
    display: block;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #3366CC;
    margin: -30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 25px;
}
ul.navbar li ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover {
    background: #4075DE 
}

ul.navbar li ul li a {
    display: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin:0px;
}

ul.navbar li:hover ul a{
    display: block;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
```

Position absolute places the element at 0,0 in it's container, so if you put it on something then don't specify the location, everything ends up on top of eachother.

Comment: Any time man. Just as an FYI, if an answer helps you and fixes the problem you can click the little upvote arrow on the post and "mark as answer", this way other people don't come here trying to answer the question later on.

Comment: Will do, i just currently have a timer.

Comment: Hah sorry thought you might be new, didn't look at your profile.